# CollapsingToolbarLayout and TabLayout results in title overlapping

Tags: android, xml, android-support-library

I'm using the CollapsingToolbarLayout and I'm trying to make the title of the activity fall nicely into its Toolbar while not overlapping with the TabLayout.

I've been searching for a couple of hours and most of the answers suggested a custom height for the Toolbar, but this results in the Title going into the lower part of the toolbar (android:gravity="bottom"). Tried changing its gravity with no luck.

Is there any way of doing this?

This is what I am getting right now:
[image: 1]

My XML layout is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/isFitSystemWindows">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/awesomeviewpager_appbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/isFitSystemWindows"
        app:layout_behavior="com.iac.awesomeviewpager.FlingBehavior"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/isFitSystemWindows"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView
                android:id="@+id/cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/raton"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/isFitSystemWindows"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/raton"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Move the tablayout out of your collapsingtoolbar layout. Hint: AppBarLayout is a LinearLayout

Comment: I'm afraid it's not quite that easy. I believe the desired effect is to let the `TabLayout` have the same background as the `Toolbar`, i.e. the ferocious animal seen in the example pictures, not forgetting the parallax effect. Hence, the `TabLayout` can't be moved outside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Comment: whats inside your viewpager? means whats your fragments containing of? just asking sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recently found myself in a similar situation as you. Unfortunately I couldn't find a nice and clean solution for this. I did, however, find a dirty XML, mish-mash solution.

One key moment was realizing that the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` will inherit it's terminal collapsed height from the first `Toolbar` within, or the one defined by the `app:toolbarId` attribute.

Once one gets past this hurdle, it's only a matter of time and patience on how to play the margins and paddings to align the final result.

The key components in the below solution are:

- The `@dimen/height` dimension
- The `@dimen/height_double` dimension
- The `app:collapsedTitleGravity="top"` attribute

The actual values of `@dimen/height` and `@dimen/height_double` are not as interesting as the relation between them; one being twice as big as the other. I think I have used `56dp` and `112dp` respectively in my tests.

I have also added semi-transparent background color attributes to the `Toolbar` and the `TabLayout` which will highlight (during runtime) what exactly is going on.

Hope you find this helpful.

***my_layout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--
            This one is interesting, especially the
            "collapsedTitleGravity" and "expandedTitleMarginBottom"
            attributes
        -->
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="top"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/height"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/pancake"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <!--
                This one is extra interesting, given the relation
                between its own height and the TabLayout height.
                The layout margins and paddings are dependant on
                text size etc.
            -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_double"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
                android:background="#33ff0000"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <!--
                And this one too, given how its "layout_height"
                attribute relates to the Toolbar.
            -->
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#3300ff00"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I've successfully tested this implementation on Android 5.1.1 and 4.4.2

Comment: This is the closest that I got, but is there any way to make the Toolbar and TabLayout collapsable (slide off the screen once the CollapsingToolbarLayout reaches the double_height)?

Comment: Good question! You could try playing with the `app:layout_scrollFlags` attribute on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` element perhaps...

Comment: Accepted because it's the closest that I could get, but really using the `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is a pain in the *** without proper documentation from Google. Especially when you can't mimic the Google Play Newsstand behaviour

Comment: Yes, it requires a bit of patience and some empirical testing sometimes :-) I have even found myself examining the source code itself to get detailed and exact answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want transparent `TabLayout` with always visibe title above do as follows:

- add `expandedTitleMarginBottom` to `CollapsingToolbarLayout`
- set `layout_height` to `TabLayout` as constant value
- add `layout_marginBottom` to `Toolbar` with same value as `TabLayout` height

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="56dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <YourMagicViewWithBackgroundImageTextAndOtherStuff
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

a very simple working solution just add this in your ToolBar. If you need I can post the full xml code

```
android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had struggled with the same issue on my layout.
And I finally got an answer from the below.

https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea

refer the comment :

"sachins commented on 18 Aug 2015"

```
The changes I made above are:

Move TabLayout out of CollapsingToolbarLayout and put it directly under CoordinatorLayout
Set these attributes inside TabLayout:
android:layout_gravity="bottom" - To make sure AppBarLayout doesn't overlap on TabLayout
app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar" and app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" - To make sure tabs appear below AppBarLayout
Also set android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" inside ViewPager to make sure TabLayout doesn't overlap any items in the list
```

to add an comment,

don't forget to remove android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from TabLayout

Comment: But wouldn't this solution place the tab bar "below" the image? I may be misunderstanding the OP's question but it seems to me an essential part of the issue is to have the tab bar share the same background image as the collapsing toolbar layout...